# How to play video from iphone's photo library in my swift app

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uiimagepickercontroller, avplayer

I have an app where I can record a video using UIImagePicker. On saving the recorded video I want to play the video in UIView within my app.

I am able to record a video and on clicking "use-video" in the UIImagePicker I am printing the video URL (url: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F9DFDFE8-467F-4DDB-A013-C076F3629F06/tmp/51411329851__5CDC14A6-053B-44C1-915D-0E87D9068D6E.MOV).
I want to load the video using the above url and play it in UIView of my app.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank You.

Comment: Use MPMoviePlayerController to play video

Comment: @DhananjayPatil MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code for playing video using AVPlayerViewController

```
let videoURL = URL(string: YOUR_URL)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
```

Comment: for playing in uiview you need to use avplayer layer

Comment: you mentioned in your question that you already got url, there is no query about fetching video .  you said "I want to load the video using the above url and play it" .  Btw you can easily create nsdata for video using this url .and save to document directory .

Comment: NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];
    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];

Comment: From my experience video should be exported with PHImageManager.default().requestExportSession(forVideo:..) method to some URL first.